# Android background service with Headless JS is not working

Tags: java, android, react-native, background-process, headless

I have implemented so far:

**MainApplication.java :**

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this); // Remove this line if you don't want Flipper enabled

    Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyTaskService.class);

    getApplicationContext().startService(service);
  }
```

**MyTaskService.java :**

```
package com.myApp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.jstasks.HeadlessJsTaskConfig;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;

public class MyTaskService extends HeadlessJsTaskService {

   @Override
  protected @Nullable HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {

Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
  WritableMap data = extras != null ? Arguments.fromBundle(extras) : null;
return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
    "SomeTaskName", // Use the registered headless Task here
    data,
    5000);
}
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
  <service android:name="com.myApp.MyTaskService" />
```

**Index.js (React-Native code):**

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('SomeTaskName', () => SomeTaskName);
```

**SomeTaskName.js (RN code):**

```
    module.exports = async (taskData) => {
    alert('test');
    console.log('Went to background');
 }
```

Using this code, it runs but closes the app right away and it doesn't display any errors. Any idea why this is happening and why I can't call the alert and console.log?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: have you found any solution for this. i also have exact same problem and nothing is working for me.

Comment: invoke the headless function from MainActivity.java  onStop() funtion

Answer (score 0):

you miss this call

```
HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(context)
```

which is required as per documentation:

> If you're starting a {@code HeadlessJsTaskService} from a {@code
> BroadcastReceiver} (e.g.  * handling push notifications), make sure to
> call {@link #acquireWakeLockNow} before returning from  * {@link
> BroadcastReceiver#onReceive}, to make sure the device doesn't go to
> sleep before the  * service is started.

Answer (score -1):

Add `Intent` in the `MainApplication.java` file and call the function `getApplicationContext()` line before `SoLoader.init()`.

Comment: still not working for me.. How will I get to know whether a task is executed or not... Not able to console or able to put alert statements?